# jQuery animate performance IE

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, jquery-animate

I built a simple animation for a carousel with jQuery animate. I always have 5 containers, 3 of them visible. When animating a new one is added and the last is removed.
Firefox and Chrome do exactly what I expect. In Internet Explorer, the moment the containers position is refreshed by "scrollLeft", the content is "blinking" and I do not know what's the reason for that effect.

This is the markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="conti">
        <div id="_ID">
            <div class="section">0</div>
            <div class="section">1</div>
            <div class="section active">2</div>
            <div class="section">3</div>
            <div class="section">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

This the script (for case of clicking next)

```
    var conti = $('#conti');
//set startposition of scrollbar (center) --> width of section
var teaserwidth = 60;
conti.scrollLeft(teaserwidth); 
var animating = false;
$('#next').click(function() {
    if(animating) return;
    animating = true;
    conti.animate({
        scrollLeft: 2*teaserwidth
    },     {
            complete: function() {
                conti.find('.section:last').after('<div style="background:red;" class="section">NF</div>');
              conti.scrollLeft(teaserwidth);
              conti.find('.section:first').remove();
              animating = false;
            }
        }
    );
});
```

I colored the new added content red to better see the blinking effect in IE.
You can also test on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/kwdPK/80/)

What would you change/suggest to have a fluid animation in IE too?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've made a slider, I've always done it by animating margin-left in IE, left in other browsers, and CSS transforms in newer browsers.

That seems to work fine.

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks for your suggestion! I rebuilt the script to this one with marginLeft animation: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kwdPK/131/) It seems to be fluid for IE now which is great. But it is "bucking" in Firefox (whoohoo). Do you think there is a way to optimize for both browsers without loading different script??

Comment: I also use CSS3 transitions in normal browsers, and only use the older javascript animation technique in legacy ones like IE9 and below. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/slide2/ shows you how to do sliding in new browsers. To make it easy to use, try either my rubbish but simple code here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/legacy/ , or just drop in http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/ if you are already using jQuery.